# Create Loader Interceptor: Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular, typescript

Pretty new in Angular and still learning it.

I try to create a Loader HTTP, which is running in UI, but I got error in console:

```
Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: 
Expression has changed after it was checked. 
Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'. 
Expression location: AppComponent component.
```

In app.module.ts

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: LoaderInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
```

LoaderInterceptor.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {finalize, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {LoaderService} from "../loader.service";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public loaderService: LoaderService) {}
  
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    this.loaderService.setIsLoading(true);
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.loaderService.setIsLoading(false))
    );
  }
}
```

LoaderService.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoaderService {

  private isLoadingSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public isLoading$ = this.isLoadingSubject.asObservable();

  setIsLoading(value: boolean) {
    this.isLoadingSubject.next(value);
  }

}
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ColorSchemeService} from './core/services/color-scheme.service';
import {LoaderService} from "./core/interceptors/loader.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
                <mat-progress-bar
                    mode="indeterminate"
                    *ngIf="loaderService.isLoading$ | async "
                />
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  title = 'MyCompany';

  constructor(public loaderService: LoaderService) {}

}
```